# How to solve "No Privileges" error in phpMyAdmin xampp

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp, wordpress-theming

I am using XAMPP for creating my WordPress Site. phpMyAdmin was working correctly but now when I try to create a new database its showing me "No Privileges" error near create database option. I am not getting any help from previous related posts

I am accessing local host by typing URL in crome as follows: localhost/dashboard and then clicking on phpMyAdmin option.

if I check the user accounts tab in the phpMyAdmin its showing following users:

[image]